# Get data from JSON column in MySql database

Tags: php, laravel

In my table there is a column with `JSON` encoded data and one record looks something like this

```
{"late_fee":10,
"due_date":"2019-10-01 00:00:00",
"property_type":"house"
}
```

When getting data from database I need records where key `late_fee` does not exist in `JSON` data column. How can I put it in `where` condition?

This is the line of code on which I have to add mentioned condition:

```
$payments = Rent::where('property_id', $property['id']);`
```

**EDIT**

By comments you posted, can you confirm me that this is the right way:

`$payments = Rent::where('property_id', $property['id'])->whereJsonContains('notification_settings->late_fee', null);`

P.S. `notification_settings` is the name of column where `JSON` data is stored.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Please always tag the question accordingly.

Comment: Mysql: '5.7.24-0ubuntu0.16.04.1'
Php: 5.6

Comment: Using `whereRaw` use `JSON_EXTRACT` to get the `late_fee` and compare the value against `IS NULL`.

Comment: @emix Thanks, can I ask you to check my edit and if that is not the right way, to write yours as an answer please?

Comment: Yes, it must work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read this short article:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#json-where-clauses

That should work :

```
$payments = Rent::where('property_id', $property['id'])->whereJsonContains('notification_settings->late_fee', null);
```

Comment: You should have mention this in comment.

Comment: Thanks, guess this should be an comment

Comment: Try to help people after that :)

Comment: This is a good answer, don't know why many downvotes, maybe you have posted 1 line answer previously